# Eslint linter notworking on vim

Tags: vim, eslint, vim-syntastic

I trying configure my `VIM` based `IDE` for work with my `js` project.

I am installed `Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic` using `vundle`.

My part of `.vimrc`:

```
 set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
 set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
 set statusline+=%*
 let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
 let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
 let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
 let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
 let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
 let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exe = 'yarn run eslint --'
```

`yarn eslint` works well

SyntasticInfo:

```
Syntastic version: 3.9.0-33 (Vim 800, Darwin)
Info for filetype: javascript
Global mode: active
Filetype javascript is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: -
Currently enabled checkers: -
```

---

after `npm install -g jslint`

`Available checkers: -` -> `Available checkers: jslint`

---

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Linter is not installed

```
npm install -g jslint
```